# Extracting specific page from multiple PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have hundreds of PDF files with same format, but different content.

I need to extract second page from every files individually.

It's like below
original1.pdf -> 2_original1.pdf
original2.pdf -> 2_original2.pdf
original3.pdf -> 2_original3.pdf

I'm trying to use PyPDF2 but I cannot figure out the code from google.

So far I used below one, but I don't think this is correct.
cd C:\Users\ukil.yeom\Desktop\pdf_extracts
convert -density 150 *.pdf[2] only-page-2.pdf

Please show me the way how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @zipper_club. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please can you update your question to include the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @AjahnCharles, I have used like below
cd C:\Users\ukil.yeom\Desktop\pdf_extracts
convert -density 150 *.pdf[2] only-page-2.pdf

But I don't think it was the correct one.

Comment: Please don't paste into the comments; use "edit" on your original question :)

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf. (I'm the maintainer of both)

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter


def extract_page(input_filepath, output_filepath, page_index):
    with open(input_filepath, "rb") as infile:
        reader = PdfReader(infile)
        writer = PdfWriter()
        writer.add_page(reader.pages[page_index])
        with open(output_filepath, "wb") as outfile:
            writer.write(outfile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # index 1 == typically what we consider the second page
    extract_page("input.pdf", "output.pdf", 1)
```